# remove rows within X minutes

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that consists of:

ID,CATEGORY,DATE_TIME

I would like like to delete rows per ID/CATEGORY that have a DATE_TIME within 5 minutes of any other record.  For example, I would like to take:

```
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:30:58
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:15:58
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:12:58
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:11:58
AAA, CAT2, 2014-12-09 18:11:58
```

And get something like this:

```
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:30:58
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:11:58
AAA, CAT2, 2014-12-09 18:11:58
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: I somewhat figured it out, but not quite what I'm wanting.   I basically did a cross-join on the dataset with itself, subtracted dates, did a date_diff, etc.  The problem is that lets me get the record that was submitted within 5 minutes, but really doesn't help me identify which submission was first.

Comment: Order your data and use the dif function

Comment: What if your third row would have a time stamp of `2014-12-09 18:15:59`, i.e. just a bit  more than 5 minutes after the fifth row?

Comment: I mean `2014-12-09 18:16:59`, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Load the data**, (I added an event just 5 minutes and a second after another event);

```
data allEvents;
    infile datalines dsd dlm=',' ;
    informat ID $3. CATEGORY $4. DATE_TIME YMDDTTM20.;
    format DATE_TIME DATETIME19.2;
    input ID $ CATEGORY $ DATE_TIME ;
    datalines;
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:30:58
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:16:59
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:15:58
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:12:58
AAA, CAT1, 2014-12-09 18:11:58
AAA, CAT2, 2014-12-09 18:11:58
;
run;
```

**Sort it on ID, CATEGORY and DATE_TIME**;

```
proc sort data=allEvents;
    by ID CATEGORY DATE_TIME;
run;
```

**Read it in a data step and filter it**;

```
data wantedEvents (drop=writtenStamp);
    set allEvents;
    by ID CATEGORY DATE_TIME;

    ** remember the last written DATE_TIME **;
    retain writtenStamp;

    if first.CATEGORY then do;
        output;
        writtenStamp = DATE_TIME;
    end;
    else if DATE_TIME GT writtenStamp + hms(0,5,0) then do;
        output;
        writtenStamp = DATE_TIME;
    end;
run;
```

**Sort it back in the original order**;

```
proc sort data=wantedEvents;
    by ID CATEGORY descending DATE_TIME ;
run;
```